# Travel 1 month before my BRP expires

Tags: uk, borders, uk-residents

Good afternoon!

I wanted to ask that I am currently in UK and working at a registered UK based company. My BRP expiration date is 30th Jan 2023. Currently I am on student visa/BRP i.e., I joined that company after the completion of my course, and they agreed to sponsor me. They have applied for the sponsorship license and I am waiting for it to apply for a work permit. Now, I need to go back to my home country for a week. Going out of UK is not an issue here, but just wondering if border police will create issues when I get back due to the BRP expiration date?

Please can someone kindly guide me regarding this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, Border Force officers can have concerns about admitting someone with a long term visa which is close to expiration. They may believe that if you're unable to extend your visa, you may end up overstaying. However, these concerns should be dispelled by explaining your plan to apply for a new visa, along with evidence that you have the ability to do so.

In your case, such evidence would ideally be evidence that a CoS has already been issued, and you are ready to make your application. However, there may be an issue if the company does not have a sponsorship licence by that point. With only 1 month remaining, they may believe it is unlikely to be granted in time for you to extend.

Are you not eligible for a Graduate visa? This could be a backup option in case your company isn't able to gain a sponsorship licence in time. In this case, you could explain your plan is to either apply for a Skilled Worker visa if the CoS comes through in time, or to apply for a Graduate visa otherwise. Evidence you can apply for the latter would be proof that you've completed your course.

Comment: Thanks much for the honest guidance, stay blessed!